# Chinese Word Segmentation

Tags: nlp

Following this paper https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D17-1079, I'm stuck with Paragraph 2 "Baseline Segmentation Model". In this section they basically explain how they feed the chinese word embeddings into the bi-LSTM model. In particular they use this formula for $e^f_i$ (forward word representation):

$$ e^f_i = concat_1(e_{w_i}, e_{w_{i−1}w_i}),
    = tanh(W_1[e_{w_i}; e_{w_{i−1}w_i}]) $$

where $w_i$ is the $i$-th character in a sentence $\{w_1,w_2,\dots,w_N\}$, where $N$ is the sentence length. We have a corresponding embedding $e_{w_i}$ and $e_{w_{i−1}w_i}$ for each character unigram $w_i$ and character bigram $w_{i−1}w_i$.

I don't really get what they are doing here and how can I replicate it with Keras?

Comment: Hello Giulia, welcome to our community. Someone more specialized in the matter may answer it here on Data Science SE but the article notation is a bit confusing, maybe you can understand it better by analyzing code.
**This is information available in the article, just to highlight it here:**
The main author in this article is [Hao Zhou](https://zhouh.github.io/) (which lab is hiring interns, by the way).

The code for that article is available in [this github repository](https://github.com/zhouh/WCC-Segmentation) and it is written in C, so could someone help her interpreting that code?